# How can remove a message specific of a file? python

Tags: python

This is my CODE:

```
old_stdout = sys.stdout
pymol.finish_launching()
log_file=open('loops.log', "w")
sys.stdout = log_file

def myfunc(resi):
    print '%s' % (resi)

file= '%s'%model_initial
x= pymol.cmd.load (file, 'r')

myspace = {'myfunc': myfunc}
d= pymol.cmd.iterate('(ss l)', 'myfunc(resi)', space=myspace)
print d

pymol.cmd.quit()
sys.stdout = old_stdout
log_file.close()

old_stdout = sys.stdout
pymol.finish_launching()
log_file=open('list.log', "w")
sys.stdout = log_file

infile = 'loops.log'
outfile = 'loops1.log'

try:

delete_list = [ "Adjusting settings to improve performance for Intel cards."]
    fin = open(infile)
    fout = open(outfile, "w+")
    for line in fin:
        for word in delete_list:
            line = line.replace(word, "")
        fout.write(line)
    fin.close()
    fout.close()

    outfile = infile

except:
    infile = infile


with open(INFILE) as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    lines = lines
    lines=lines[:-1]
    lines=map(int, lines)  #Convert str list to int list
    lines=lines[:-1]
    lines=map(int, lines)  #Convert str list to int list

def group_runs(li,tolerance=2):
    out = []
    last = li[0]
    for x in li:
        if x-last > tolerance:
            yield out
            out = []
        out.append(x)
        last = x
    yield out

print list(group_runs(lines))

sys.stdout = old_stdout
log_file.close()

old_stdout = sys.stdout
pymol.finish_launching()
log_file=open('list.log', "w")
sys.stdout = log_file

fhand=open('list.log')
for lines in fhand:
    print lines

for k, g in groupby(enumerate(lines), lambda (i,x):i-x):
            ranges = []
            group = map(itemgetter(1), g)
            ranges.append((group[0], group[-1]))
            print ranges

sys.stdout = old_stdout
log_file.close()
```

the file loops.log, is a file with many numbers (select them of model initial, and the function principal of this CODE is group them for example:

1

2

3

4

8

9

11

15

group them:

(1,4)

(8,9)

(11, 11)

(15, 15)

This CODE works, but, when file have many many numbers, I have this message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./automaticvF.py", line 232, in <module>
    lines=map(int, lines)  #Convert str list to int list
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Adjusting settings to improve performance for Intel cards.
```

and the log is white. I Think that is more easy remove the message of my file loops.log, and change name of file. this only happens when have many many many numbers to group, but when I have 80 numbers for example, no problem. so What can I change in this CODe, for use the variable infile, depending if the message is or not is in the infile old?

Can somebody help me please?

Thanks

Comment: The error happens because this line ("Adjusting settings to improve performance for Intel cards.") is contained in your input file.

Comment: How can  avoid printing  this message in the input file ?
When there Is a low number of elements ( numbers ) in the input file , not  happens.

Comment: You might want to tell us how your input file is generated.

Comment: Yes, in this case, is a file with 515 numbers in a list format, and I just want group them like I said above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of redirecting the standard output of your process to a file by changing sys.stdout, you need to write your data to the file directly. You can do it, for example, like this:

```
print >> log_file, '%s' % (resi)
```

Or like this:

```
log_file.write(str(resi))
```

This will ensure that your file will not contain random unrelated data that happens to be printed to the standard output.

Comment: I did it, but I no had a positive result. I'm beginner in python, so.. I think ..isn't more easy remove the message? I updated the code, how can I use the variable infile in the function, depending if the message is or not is? Can you help me please